# ASP .NET Response content being cut off - weird bug

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

I have a problem with my application which happens only once it is deployed on publication server. My app returns errors `System.Web.HttpException invalid request` on Webresource.axd
The requested WebResource URL by the clients is for exemple : (ignore the ** and * they are used to seperate part of the url)

> WebResource.axd?d=**PLZ1f5srE_3_5bqe5SNJORbrjr9bvaTarv3MMKJi1fn**GsDQLshr2sDQLshrmsDQLshrWsDQLshrGsDQLshq2sDQLshumvDQL72ZKbBQK5zYfpBAK5zZuMAwLEytPECwLbo5IqArrNo5oDAsbKp5sDAsbK66oFArnN28ILArnNj9UCAsfK8/UJAqTNm4oJAv2jypsOAvCjpoIOAsbK/6EDArnN254FAsbKh70KAqTNg7wKAqTNw84NAsTKm9ACAsbK8/UJAtyj+uUHAsfKz+cEArnNg+gEAqTN1+UEArnNv78KAsfK560FArrNg7wKArnNr5kDAqTNr5kDAsbKo5oDAsfKm9ACAv2jpoIOAsfK6/cJArnN0+QEArnN560FArnN08QLAv2jzpgOAsbK5/YJAqTN28ILAsbKo+AEAqTNk9ICArnN350DAsbKm9ACAsbK44kJAqfNn4sJArnNs4YDArnN76sFArjNl9MCAsbK6/cJArnN7/QJAqTN0/0JAsbKi7oKAqfNm4oJAv2j+uUHAsfKi7oKArnN44kJArnNu74KAsbKi9QCArnN5/YJAqTNz+cEArnNm4oJAsbKt4cDAsTK5/YJArnNh70KArnNp8ELArnNt4cDArnNn9ECAtrKm9ACAsbKj9UCArnNn4sJAsbK7/QJArnNi9QCArnNy8wNAsTK+8ANAsbKs4YDAqTNi9QCAsfKk9ICArnNl9MCAvqjpoIOArnNo+AEArnNs7AKArnN0/0JAsfKo5oDAsbK/8ENAsfK08QLAsbKk9ICAsbK0+QEAr3Nl9MCAsbK3+MEAsfK+8ANAsbK+8ANArnNg7wKAt3Km9ACArnN/8YCArnN3+MEArnNq5gDAvujpoIOArnNi7oKAsfK5/YJArnNk9ICArnN/8ENAqfNo5oDArnNz+cEArrN560FArnNr7UMAt3K5/YJAsfK3+MEAqTN/6EDArrN/6EDAtyjkioCp83nrQUCxMqLugoCuc3Dzg0CpM3TxAsCp82DvAoCxsqf0QICvc3nrQUC26PmzggCpM3L5gQCpM2fiwkCp83/oQMCpM2jmgMCuc23sQoCuc2H1wICxMrr9wkCuc3rowoCuc3r9wkCus2X0wICp82X0wICuc3z9QkCuc2jmgMCuc37lgUCx8qHvQoCp83P5wQCuc3voAoCuc2b0AICxsrTxAsCxMqjmgMCpM2X0wIC3crr9wkCus23sQoCxsrP5wQCxsrnrQUC26P65QcCuc37wA0Cuc3/oQMCpM37wA0Cp823sQoCuc2XjwMCuc3rqgUCpM3nrQUCuc3X+gkCuc3PzQ0C/aOGig4Cuc2HyQsCxsq7vgoCuc3X5QQC+qPKmw4Cuc2nmwMCuc3L5gQCuc2zsgwCxsq3sQoC/aPmzggCpM23sQoCuc3DxwIC3KPmzggCh+rGqAgChKbr/g4***keCbLSNH7D5G4o/WMirW0wCCoaA==

So two thing hit me right away :

1. The missing &t= at the end for the assembly timestamp
2. There are "/" and "+" which does not seem to be usually found in encrypted url

I ran the application on my side of course everything works fine for me... but I noticed in my source file that parts of what I see in the clients error can be found in my html :

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=**PLZ1f5srE_3_5bqe5SNJORbrjr9bvaTarv3MMKJi1fn**NUlSwWXFIxNUWR37nSX-uEeFiuIaj75QpNoWiMNuwvLvtF14FC7RJnWXlWsiRGRTxygC60zWpEKm8nsH2W5C_3w9fBgmsUvMtxxfwjQB23ipcHaCWFd_wvS5QWc5bgmPzUpNNF-gwwdthk8-NKZOJKbUxQg2&amp;amp;t=634601510084481499" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<!-- SOME MORE CODE -->

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="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" />
```

Notice the first part of the "bad URL" :

> PLZ1f5srE_3_5bqe5SNJORbrjr9bvaTarv3MMKJi1fn

Can be found in the script tag of my HTML 
and the second part of the bad URL :

> 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

Can be found in the input tag of my html.

So anyway I guess the client receive html code that has been corrupted / cut off I don't know or mixed up with another request. Could also be that production is on iis 6 while developement is on iis 7. Production server is also using SSL so not sure if this could interfere. Could it be the Server.Transfer in my code?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the WebResouce.axd for? I am assuming you are not adding in the unique identifier yourself (which would be the obvious issue if you were).

Comment: All of that base64 text makes your question hard to read, and doesn't add any useful info.

Comment: just wild guess, is IIS urlscan installed on that production server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's IE8 Lookaheahd Downloader. The bug is transparent to users so we simply ignore the errors.

[ASP.NET Causing Corrupted HTML with WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd](http://www.alterprocedure.net/articles/alterprocedure/aspnet-causing-corrupted-html-with-webresourceaxd-and-scriptresourceaxd.aspx)

[Bugs in IE8's Lookahead Downloader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/bugs-in-the-ie8-lookahead-downloader.aspx)

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer has a [2083-character limit on URLs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

Your `__EVENTVALIDATION` validation parameter alone is 1877 characters long. Added to the rest of the URL (not clear from the question, but possibly something similar to what in `src` of the `script` element), you're above that limit.

You may find that you have to use HTTP POST for that sort of request (due to the length).

What could explain the difference between the dev. and production server is that you may have a shorter base URL on your dev. machine (e.g. `localhost` would be shorter than `www.example.com`), since you're just around the actual limit, it may still work on your dev. server.